# Convert array to comma delimited string

Tags: javascript

I have the following array:

```
var ids = [1, 5, 28, 8];
```

I need to split the array into a string separated by a `,`:

Example result: `"1, 5, 28, 8"`

Comment: Use the `.join()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example simply shows converting your array of numbers into an array of strings:

`ids = [1, 5, 28, 8]` to `ids = "1","5","28","8"`

That is done through a call to `Array.map`

```js
var ids = [1, 5, 28, 8];
ids = ids.map(id => ''+id);

console.log(ids);
```

This converts each number in the array into a string in the array.

---

If you want your array of numbers to be converted into a single string like this:

`ids = [1, 5, 28, 8]` to `ids = "1,5,28,8"`

Then you simply need to use `Array.join`

```js
var ids = [1, 5, 28, 8];
ids = ids.join(',');

console.log(ids);
```

This creates a single strings that separates each array entry with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Use map function to map each element to quoted string, then join all elements to single string.

```
[1, 5, 28, 8].map(x => `"${x}"`).join(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the reduce function:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].reduce( (sum,val) => sum + ',' + val );
```

Output:

```
"1,2,3,4,5"
```

If you dont provide an initial value to the reduce function then it just uses the first value in the array as the sum, and starts reducing from the second value onwards.

Answer (score 0):

With join

```
var ids = [1, 5, 28, 8];

let string ids.join(',');
console.log(string);
```

Output

```
"1, 5, 28, 8"
```